# Login de cliente com credenciais de acesso à noticias

Tags: php, wordpress, email

## Explicação:

Possuo um cadastro de clientes no post_type através de *metaboxes*, onde há os campos *email* e *senha*, e o nome do cliente é o `the_title();`

## Objetivo:

Preciso fazer um login com os campos *email* e *senha* e verificar se existe algum cliente (post_type) com essas credenciais.

## Observações:

Tenho um post_type de noticias, que ao serem inseridas são direcionadas para um cliente específico, ou seja, ao logar, só poderá ter acesso à noticias direcionadas ao cliente que estiver logado.

Comment: Alguem pra me ajudar?

Comment: Seja mais específico, o que já experimentou até agora? Cole aqui o seu código php relativo à sua questão

Comment: Já consegui gente. Obrigada pela atenção.

Comment: Poste a solução que encontrou e marque como aceita. Assim pode ajudar futuros usuários com o mesmo problema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/* Resolução que encontrei: */

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'clientes',
        'meta_query'=> array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'email',
                'value' => $email,
                'compare' => '='
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'senha',
                'value' => $senha,
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );  

    $cliente_args = new WP_Query( $args ); 



/*Buscar noticias que possuem o ID (GET) no metabox; */ 
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'noticias',
                'meta_query'=> array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'clientes',
                        'value' => $_GET['id'],
                        'compare' => '='
                    )
                )
            );  
            $clientes = new WP_Query($args);
```